# Swift - For Loop crashed

Tags: ios, swift, email, uiimageview

maybe you can help me out here...
I am creating an email body based on my core data entity "plants"

```
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let todos = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Plants")
    var row = ""

    var circle = 0 as Int

    var fetchresults:Array<AnyObject> = []


    fetchresults = contxt.executeFetchRequest(todos, error: nil)!

    var endcircle = fetchresults.count as Int





    for index in 0...endcircle {

        let object = fetchresults[index] as! NSManagedObject
        var name = object.valueForKey("name") as! String


        var newlineimg = "nil"
        var newlineplant = (name) + "<br>"
        row = (row + newlineimg + newlineplant) as String

    }


   var mail = row
```

The App crashes without an error...I seem to can't find the error in the code...

Comment: You would find the error quickly if you use the *debugger* and step through the code. Then it would become apparent that the loop is executed more often than expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You enumerate one loop to much, it should be:

```
for index in 0...(endcircle - 1)
```

or

```
for index in 0..<endcircle
```

when your `fetchresults.count` is for example 5 and you enumerate from 0 to 5 it's actually 6 loops, thats why it's failed.

Comment: Or `for index in 0 ..< endcircle `. Even better, avoid the index and enumerate the array: `for object in fetchresults { ... }`.

Comment: Sometimes the little errors are the greatest ones. thank you very much for this one!